# string length and compare to int

Tags: c#, substring, string-length

Why does this not work ?
if teaserLength for example returns 300, then it is true. 
if it returns for example 37, it is false.. Even though it is supposed to be reversed...

my code:

```
@{
     int teaserLength = item.TeaserText.Length;
}
@if (teaserLength >= 75)
{
     @item.TeaserText
}
else { 
     @item.TeaserText.Substring(1, 75)
}
```

And why does a TeaserText with a length of 37, give a

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
```

on substring ?

Comment: Because you are literally saying `if the teaserLength is smaller than 75, take the substring`?

Comment: substring starts at index 0. same way arrays are used.

Comment: @IanH. am i not saying, if teaserText is less than or equal to 75, use teaser text. else if bigger use substring ?

Comment: You are saying if teaserText is less than 75, take a substring of 75 characters (and there aren't that many to take - you only have 37!) starting at index 1 (which is the second character). What do you **WANT** it to do?

Comment: You could just get rid of the `teaserLength` variable and the `if/else` altogether and return `@item.TeaserText.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.TeaserText.Length, 75));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "starting" index in `Substring` is zero-based, and you only want the substring if the length is 75 or more:

```
@if (teaserLength >= 75)
{
     @item.TeaserText.Substring(0, 75)
}
else { 
     @item.TeaserText
}
```

or just

```
@item.TeaserText.Substring(0, Math.Min(teaserLength, 75))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to make use of the [`Min`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5sbzt2y(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
@{
    int maxCharsToDisplay = Math.Min(item.TeaserText.Length, 75);
}

@item.TeaserText.Substring(0, maxCharsToDisplay);
```

For those cases where the value is less than 75, `Min` will return that length; where the value is greater, `75` will be returned. You should only ever have at most 75 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Read your own `if` statements again.

```
@if (teaserLength >= 75)
{
     @item.TeaserText
}
else { 
     @item.TeaserText.Substring(1, 75)
}
```

"If `teaserLength` is **greater than or equal to** 75, use the text, else take the substring."

You cannot take a substring with length 75 of a string, of which the length is smaller than 75.

To solve this error, simply switch out your `>=` operator for a `<` operator.

Also, you probably want to switch your `.Substring(1, 75)` out for `.Substring(0, 75)`, assuming you want to truncate the string to 75 characters.
As @RufusL correctly mentioned, you will get an exception for a string with length 75 otherwise.

Comment: Why not fix your answer instead of just noting that you'll get an exception?

Comment: @DStanley What's wrong with my answer? I stated what can cause the error and provided a solution.

Comment: It's not _wrong_ (and I didn't downvote) but it would be more complete to incorporate the index fix into the answer rather than adding a side note.

Comment: @DStanley With _answer_, do you mean the code snippet? The snippet provided in the answer is identical with the one in the question - i included it solely to make the reader aware of the mistake while reading.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to use `System.Linq` and just `Take` the max number of items you want (75) and then `Concat` them:

```
string.Concat(item.TeaserText.Take(75));
```